# Креш в Ruby on Rails (ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет. В руби я фактически новичок посему сильно не пинайте)) 
в Роллбар вылезает периодически ошибка 
**ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**
Ниже-кусок кода где rollbar видает ошибку.

```
- if collection.any? 
  table.table.data-table.table-details.private-counts cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0"
    thead
      tr
        th Асoount
        th Service provider
        th Information
        - if current_user.accounts.count > 1
          th Actions
    tbody
       - collection.each do |account|
        - consumer = current_user.consumer_info(account.identifier)
        tr
          td= account.identifier
          td
            - @service_providers[account.identifier.to_sym].each do |sp|
              div
                - provider = ServiceProvider.find_by_code(sp.service_provider_code)
                span= provider.try(:name)
```

Comment: Руби? Может раби?

Comment: Продумайте загаловок. Отформатируйте для удобства понимания вашего вопроса.

Comment: ruby  ver. 1.9.1 ))

Comment: @Flippy именно руби.

Comment: поставить проверку - это не правильно. правильно - будет понять, а почему там **nil** появляется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую! Во всём виноват `@service_providers[account.identifier.to_sym]`
На collection у Вас имеется проверка.
В целом во вьюхе делать подобную "операцию" странно, ибо вы берете значение по ключу из хеша. Очевидно что ключа может не быть, а если его нет, то Вам вернут `nil`, что собственно и происходит.
Более того Вы делаете обращение к базе в цикле, во вьюхе. Это негоже. Найдите необходимых провайдеров в контроллере и в цикле обходите их.
Контроллер:

```
codes = @service_providers[account.identifier.to_sym]
provider_codes = codes.map(&:service_provider_code) if codes
@providers = ServiceProvider.find_by_codes(provider_codes) if provider_codes
```

Заметьте, что Вам нужен метод `find_by_codes`, который найдет несколько провайдеров, по массиву кодов. Это можно написать проще и красивей, но я написал конкретно для вашего примера.

Во вьюхе уже сделать подобно тому что Вы делали с коллекцией.

```
- if @providers.any?
  - @providers.each do |provider|
    div
      span = provider.try(:name)
```

Или если по красивому

```
- [*@providers].each do |provider|
    div
      span = provider.try(:name)
```

P.S.
`[*@providers]` возвращает коллекцию если таковая имеется, и пустой массив если коллекция `nil`.

Comment: Не помогло..начали крешать даже те страницы которые не крешали раньше. Касательно самого контроллера ааков секция index первоначально выглядит так:
` def index    
    @accounts          = current_user.accounts.order('main DESC')
    @service_providers = current_user.service_providers
  end `

Comment: пока что поборол таким способом креш в вьюхе [*@service_providers[account.identifier.to_sym]]